# nginx matching similar, but wrong location

Tags: nginx

I have a few exposed `JSON` scripts / programs for quick information gathering from a server. I use nginx to expose those as just raw urls. So given the following locations:

```
location ~ ^/api/status/? {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /path/to/some/handler/wan.handler;
}

location ~ ^/api/status-lan/? {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /path/to/some/handler/lan.handler;
}
```

Why does `nginx` match my `status-lan` call to the `status` location? So I can view my output from `/api/status/` just fine, but if I view `/api/status-lan/` I get the `status` location instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does nginx match my status-lan call to the status location?

Because the location is a regular expression, and this regular expression:

```
location ~ ^/api/status/? {
```

means "starts with /api/status, followed by an optional trailing slash", what comes after the match doesn't matter.

The config should probably be:

```
location ~ ^/api/status/?$ {
    rewrite ^ /path/to/some/handler/wan.handler;
}

location ~ ^/api/status-lan/?$ {
    rewrite ^ /path/to/some/handler/lan.handler;
}
```

I.e. match the whole url, not just the start of it. If in doubt, turn on [the rewrite log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log) as it'll make it obvious what is happening, and why.

Comment: Ah match the ENTIRE url, missed that. I'm a tad new to `nginx` so learning about that rewrite log is going to help a lot!